# Google Sheets - Arrayformula Query Split debugging

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I manually copy and paste some data from pdf tables.
I've been using array query split to split that info into different columns and it works flawless in 2 columns (date and amount) and for the other one it works most of the time (reference).

**Example that works:**

- PDF DATA: 4500063794 21.07.2020 187.50
- COLUMNS IN SPREADSHEET (final result after split): Reference:4500063794, Date:21.07.2020, Amount:187.50
- Formula for retrieving Reference column: `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(C3:C7 ;" ");"select Col1";0))`
- This works along the spreadsheet without any problems

**Another example that works:**

- PDF DATA: 447/20.6TBOS 04.07.2020 804.00
- COLUMNS IN SPREADSHEET (final result after split): Reference:447/20.6TBOS, Date:04.07.2020, Amount:804.00
- Formula for retrieving Reference column: `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(C3:C7 ;" ");"select Col1";0))`
- This works along the spreadsheet without any problems

**Example that DOES NOT work:**

- If I paste several rows like 1st example and then add several rows as the 2nd example, when I paste afterwards more data like the one in 1st example, split stops retrieving the Reference column for pdf data similar to "447/20.6TBOS 04.07.2020 804.00" (2nd example). It retrieves blank cells for these.

Can anyone shine a light on this?
Thanks in advance

[Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cUK-dwZW7NLelf5gNO-_YL0By37H2MNUHVS_VmQKo8g/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you change the query to:

`=ArrayFormula(INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(C3:C7; "\s"; "♥");"♥");ROW(C3:C7)-ROW(C3);1))`

The formula will replace the spaces by hearts (rare character) and then it will populate the rest.

To change the values of the rows, just change the last character 1 to 2 or 3:
`)-ROW(C3); ==> 1 ))`

[image]

You can use the same formula to the `G` column (don't forget to update the ranges), as the delimiters of both of the `4500063794 21.07.2020 187.50` and the `447/20.6TBOS 04.07.2020 804.00` are the same (whitespaces).